# Dynamic detail with smoothing

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

Is there a way for the sculpted area to smooth as you sculpt dynamic detail on it. I might be missing something obvious, but as you sculpt with dynamic topology, smaller polygons are added, but the surface is not smoothed, creating that jagged shading. I think this behaves the same way when using a Subsurf modifier put on "Simple" instead of "Catmull-Clark".

In blender:

[image]
[image]

However, Sculptris on the other hand smooths the surface and there's no problem adding more detail.

[image]
[image]

I find it that only the Snake and Smooth brush are working fine for this. Is there a way to sculpt with smoothing somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hold down the Shift key while making a brush stroke, the Smooth Brush will become active until you release the Shift key.

Sculptris uses what people call auto-relax smoothing.

I don't believe that Blender currently has anything analogous to that feature.

There is a thread hosted on Blender Artists that has been going for a couple years now and it's topic is Dynatopo sculpting.

There are many tips sprinkled here and there if you read through the whole thing.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?264568-Dyntopo-tests/page249&highlight=sculpting

Comment: I just found this link - https://nicholasbishop.net/?p=474 - where a blender developer or something like that mentioned "Surface relaxation (to fix blocky appearance after subdivision)" in the section of the things that are yet to be done so now it's obvious that this is not yet supported in Blender. Thanks for the answer :)